# How can I diagnose recurring but unpredictable brief system hangs?

Tags: linux, freeze, diagnostic

Yesterday, I wiped my `/` folder and installed a new version of Linux over my old executables, retaining my data mounted on other partitions and drives. Since then, the system will periodically hang for 1-2 seconds on input. The hangs aren't reproducible, and don't really cause any problems, but they're definitely recurring, and incredibly annoying. They seem to happen in clusters, recurring several times in a few minutes and then not at all for longer stretches of time.

I just built this PC less than a year ago, and it didn't have this problem at all before I reinstalled the operating system. I can think of any number of things this problem could be related to, including incomplete implementation of Skylake HD530 integrated graphics in the kernel (which I was actually upgrading Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 in order to attempt to fix.) But is there a way to actually diagnose this problem and to determine what process is causing it?

While there are some (many) apparent duplicates of this question, most seem to address issues with Windows that are not applicable to me, much less with a freshly installed OS (albeit a 'testing' branch). Those I've reviewed that do apply to Linux are more critical freezes than simple hangs on input. I'm not even sure how to describe this problem concisely, as a 'freeze' or a 'hang' is usually more fatal than a short pause in execution -- the thing is, I don't know why execution should pause at all, as I'm not doing anything at all processor-intensive, just browsing the web and, for example, editing shell scripts. I welcome the insight of the community in helping me identify this issue.

Output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
04:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801 (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
```

Edit: As to how I upgraded Linux, `rm -rf /` isn't too far from reality, except that I reformatted only my 'system' partition, which is mounted at `/`, and then installed a new Linux from scratch. My keyboard is an HP KB-1156, in case that matters.

Comment: any possibility you could post the output of lspci ?  Just wondering what other hardware you might have that could be missing drivers.   Would it be an option to reinstall using 15.10 to see if these problems are still happening (I am going to imagine they wont, but who knows)?

Comment: Can you explain how you upgraded the OS? "I wiped my / folder and installed a new version of Linux over my old executables" seems to imply you did a "rm -fr /" or something. What kind of keyboard do you have?